# How to find the End position of a Ray(Vector3) using a Range(Float)?

Tags: c++, math, vector

Not sure if the title really represents what I want to find out.

But simply said, I want to Raycast in my scene and check if the Ray intersects with something.
To do this I plan to do a collision check with a Position that is along the ray, updating that position using a Lerp between the Start and End point of the Ray. Where I use a for loop to get my *t* of the Lerp.

The problem is, that I only have the Start position, and the Facing direction of the Ray.
I don't have the end point which I need to Lerp between. But I do have a Float that represents the Range.

So something along the lines of:

```
RayCast(vector3 start, vector3 Direction, float range) // Direction is a normalized vector
{
    vector3 PositionAlongRay = start;
    vector3 end = ???;

    for(int t = 0; t < range; t++)
    {
        PositionAlongRay = Lerp(start, end, t);
        
        if(Collision Check) // some collision function to compare PositionAlongRay with a object
        {
            // Ray Collided, do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

So my question, how can I get the End position of my Ray using a Range value?

It is a problem that seems very simple but is new to me, and searching up anything about it just throws me to questions that are answered with Engine specific replies that have already got this basic math stuff already  implemented. (Maybe I just don't know how to search).

- Initially I thought of just adding the range to each of the vector3 components (ie. Ray.x + range), but that didnt make sense to me since you may first of all move only in certain directions, and second maybe only some amount of the max range on a specific axis.
  ie.

  ```
  vector3 end = vector3(start.x + range, start.y + range, start.z + range);
  ```
- Then I thought about multiplying the range by the direction vector since its normalized. But I am not sure if this the correct approach? Because the ray (unless one of the axis is exactly 1.0f) will never actually reach the full 'range' that its supposed to be able to travel up to, since usually the direction is somewhere in between 0-1 but never exactly at either.

  ```
  vector3 end = vector3(start.x + (direction.x * range), start.y + (direction.y * range), start.z + (direction.z * range));
  ```

Comment: `start + direction * range` is the way to go, but hard to say what your `range` is. Theoretically, the "ray" is infinite